# Validar un registro en una list de dict, si lo encuentra, actualizarlo, sino, insertarlo

Tags: python

Tengo un problema menor, por mi comprensión de cómo funciona esto. Tengo una función para jugar el juego de los dados, para luego enviar los resultados en una lista a otra función donde valido los resultados de los dados, la lista toma el nombre del jugador y los valores de los dados, se ve así:

```
['John', 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Luego estoy tratando de guardar el registro en un dict, para luego guardarlo en una nueva lista, donde estará toda la información de los jugadores, se verá así:

```
[ 
  {
   'Nombre': 'luis',
   'Dados': (1, 2, 3, 3, 3),  
   'Apuesta': 500 
  },  {
    'Nombre': 'andrew',
    'Dados': (2, 2, 2, 1, 2),
    'Apuesta': 500 
  } 
]
```

Pero no sé cómo hacer lo siguiente:

1. Si la lista está vacía, sin diccionarios de jugadores, guardar el primero en base a una previa validación.
2. Una validación es que compruebe si la "key" Nombre ya tiene el "value" del nombre del jugador, si es así, no inserte uno nuevo, como el primer punto, si no que le actualice el valor de la "key" dados a los nuevos valores de los dados que recibe.

Aquí está mi código completo:

```
datos_jugadores = []
def validar_valores(list_valores):
    dados = list_valores[1], list_valores[2],  list_valores[3],  list_valores[4],  list_valores[5]
    jugador = {
            "Nombre": list_valores[0], 
            "Dados": dados,
            "Apuesta": 500
        }
    if(1 not in list_valores):
        print(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + list_valores[0] + ", no has tenido suerte, por favor, cede tu turno." + Style.RESET_ALL)
        os.system('pause')
        lanzar_dados()
    else:
        # datos_jugadores.append(jugador)
        # next((item for item in datos_jugadores if item["name"] == list_valores[0]), None)
        for dato in datos_jugadores:
            if(dato["Nombre"] != list_valores[0]):
                datos_jugadores.append(jugador)
                continue
            else:
                dato["Nombre"]["Dados"] = dados
        contar_unos = list_valores.count(1)
        print("Se encontraron: ", str(contar_unos) , " unos.")
        print(datos_jugadores)
        os.system('pause')
        lanzar_dados()

def lanzar_dados():
    os.system('cls')
    valores_dados = []
    valores_dados.clear()
    print(Fore.GREEN + "Hola jugador, mide tu suerte, ¿Cuál es tu nombre? : " + Style.RESET_ALL)
    nombre_jugador = input().lower()
    valores_dados.append(nombre_jugador)

    dado_uno = r.randint(1,3)
    valores_dados.append(dado_uno)

    dado_dos = r.randint(1,3)
    valores_dados.append(dado_dos)

    dado_tres = r.randint(1,3)
    valores_dados.append(dado_tres)

    dado_cuatro = r.randint(1,6)
    valores_dados.append(dado_cuatro)

    dado_cinco = r.randint(1,6)
    valores_dados.append(dado_cinco)
    
    print(valores_dados)
    os.system('pause')
    validar_valores(valores_dados)
    return valores_dados

dados = lanzar_dados()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para simplificar todos esos problemas puedes cambiar la estructura de datos y crear un diccionario de diccionarios.

Piensa en un diccionario del estilo:

```
judadores = {'pepe': {
        'Dados': [2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
        'Apuesta': 500}
```

El nombre del jugador es la **clave** del diccionario `jugadores` y el valor es un diccionario `jugador` que creas en cada nueva jugada.
Si vuelva a jugar **Pepe** python se encarga de todo lo que pides.

Para tirar los dados puedes usar un `for` y ahorras bastante código.

```
def lanzar_dados():
    os.system('cls')

    judadores = { }
    fr = (Fore.GREEN + "Hola jugador, mide tu suerte, ¿Cuál es tu nombre? : " + Style.RESET_ALL)
    nombre_jugador = input(fr).lower()
    
    #    Creas un nuevo diccionario para guardar los nuevos valores
    jugador = {
        'Apuesta': 0,
        'Dados': []
    }

    jugador['Apuesta'] = input(f'Cuánto apuestas?:   ')

    #    Lanza los dados
    for i in range(6):
        input(f'{nombre_jugador.title()} pulsa enter para tirar el dado {i+1}')
        jugador['Dados'].append(randint(1,3))

    #   Cuenta los 1
    print(f"{nombre_jugador} tienes {jugador['Dados'].count(1)}")

    #   Guarda los datos en el dicc jugadores

    judadores[nombre_jugador] = jugador
```

Comment: Definitivamente es mucho mas sencillo de esta manera, compa Tomy, gracias por tu ayuda y tiempo!